# circumradius of a special octagon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

.

A similar question has been discussed but that is the case of a hexagon which is a much simpler case as after shuffling the sides and drawing a diagonal we get a cyclic quadrilateral and then appropriate theorems can be used but in this case we get a Pentagon.

The other similar question has been put on hold

Comment: Add more details to reopen. I vote to reopen now!

Answer (score 2):

The person asking has implicitly promised you that the answer is independent of the order of the sides.  Otherwise there would be various answers depending on the order.  (As pointed out by J" it is easy to see the order of sides does not matter).  To take advantage of this, choose your favorite arrangement.  Mine is $a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b$.  In the figure below, let the short sides be $a$ and the long sides be $b$.  Length $CH=i=a+b\sqrt 2$.  The diameter of the circumcircle is $j=\sqrt {i^2+a^2}=\sqrt{2a^2+2\sqrt 2 ab+2b^2}$, which is symmetric in $a,b$ as it must be.  The circumradius is half this.

[image]

Comment: Note that the order of the sides never matter. The angle subtended by each of the sides will always add up to $2\pi$ regardless of order.

Comment: @J'':  A very good point.  I have updated.

Comment: This question has been asked very recently by YOU, @LifeRacer8 (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436593) and moreover put ON HOLD. It is against the rules of this site to ask it again.